# Data deduplication - Postfix server?

Tags: linux, email, debian, postfix-mta, deduplication

I have a mail server running Postfix. Each message is saved as a file in filesystem, so I'm figuring out if there is a way to reduce duplicated files and so reduce disk space usage.

I tried to install and use opendedup, but I really did not understand how it works. The official quickstart guide just does not mention anything about which phisical disk it will use (I wish enable dedup just on /dev/sdb1, or so).

I know that using deduplication on Microsoft Windows Server is really easy and it works fine, I was figuring out if there was a way to make an iSCSI server using Windows Server, turn dedup on it, and map that iSCSI on debian that is running Postfix. But that really looks weird =/

btw, I'm running the Postfix server on Hyper-V servers.

I really need provide larger mailboxes, if I cannot get it using Linux and Postfix, they will spend lots of money on Microsoft Exchange or something so.

Comment: Unless you have multiple users subscribed to high-volume mailing lists via a local alias or something like that (which is easily an obvious optimization point -- offer the list as a newsgroup instead, or something -- see http://gmane.org/), you should find that each message is unique, so deduplication won't really help here anyway. Various `Received:` headers etc contain delivery details unique to each message.  If you can, and want to, factor these out, that's a substantial development project.

Comment: Do you think that even working on block level, that won't work?

Comment: No actual measurements available to assess the feasibility of that, but I'd doubt it. As suggested by @starkers, compression seems like a more promising idea. But none of this is on-topic for SO, which is a programming site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Opendedup as a postfix server. It mounts as a virtual filesystem ontop of an existing filesystem to provide deduplication to the mountpoint. With variable block deduplication you should get good deduplication rates.

The [quickstart guid](http://www.opendedup.org/quickstart)e should help you get started.

Answer (score -1):

Silly questions but to provide bigger mailboxes why don't you get more storage and mount it like a normal admin?

iSCSI should be importable by hyper-v and provided the VM has LVM you simple import the new disk into the disk group and expand the FS.

Alternatively you could try the best dedup in the business (ZFS) but if you can't figure out OpenDedup this may be too challenging.

The linux implementation (http://zfsonlinux.org/) is not truely stable in my opinion (I've been running it for over a year at home but I would not run it on production just yet...

For production I recommend talking to http://www.ixsystems.com/ or getting familiar with FreeNAS and FreeBSD's ZFS.. Alternatively IllumOS or a similar Solaris offshoot.

IIRC The rule of thumb for ZFS dedup is that you require 5Gb of ram for every Tb of data or performance will be heavily impacted. I personally and professionally use LZO compression instead of dedup.  (NB: ZFS does block-level dedup)

In terms of other linux deduplication systems I'm not aware of anything that I would put on production.. That being said however compression is certainly a good solution worth concidering!!

Many stable FS'es support on the fly compression, ext4 and reiserfs of the top of my head.

Brtfs (opensource's answer to ZFS) also has great LZO compression See: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=btrfs_lzo_2638&num=2

I didn't enjoy the performance of btrfs last time I tried it however.

There are many other options but suggest you check the matrix of file systems on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Note that NTFS is unaware of checksums on its filesystem, I would not use this in production.

Basically data is not safe without b-tree style checksums (ZFS) or hardware raid (BBU backed). I'd take zfs over hardware raid anyday, no write-holes.